# Control PHP scandir via html form

Tags: php, html, forms, scandir

I'm building a file-sort tool using PHP and the scandir function. So far what I've got is a simple HTML doc with included PHP that prints out all files of a specific directory - yay. It also does this based on the files names in ascending or descending order, depending on the PHP script I'm using. Now what I'm trying to build is a HTML Form with two radio buttons and a submit button changing the PHP script: it should show the list either ascending or descending. Here is my html form:

```
<div class="controls">
    <form class="controlform">
        <input type="radio" name="valone" value="Milk">Ascending
        <input type="radio" name="valtwo" value="Milk">Descending
        <button class="sortbutton">Sort!/button><br>
    </form>
</div>
```

...a few line later in the HTML doc this is what my PHP script looks like:

```
<?php

$dir = "files";
$exclude = array( ".","..","error_log","_notes" );
if (is_dir($dir)) {
$files = scandir($dir 
    // adding this for descending order ,SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING
    );
foreach($files as $file){
    if(!in_array($file,$exclude)){
        echo '
        <li> ' . $file . ' </li>';
    }
 }
}
?>
```

Now the question is: how do I get this working? Thank you very much!

// UPDATE & FINAL SOLUTION

Thank you very much for the answers! THIS is the working solution:

HTML

```
            <form class="controlform" method="get" action="index.php">
                    <input type="radio" name="sort" value="asc">Ascending
                    <input type="radio" name="sort" value="desc">Descending
                    <button class="sortbutton">Sort!</button><br>
            </form>
```

PHP

```
            <?php
            $sortFlag = SCANDIR_SORT_NONE; // set a default
            if (!empty($_GET['sort'])) {
                switch ($_GET['sort']) {
                    case 'asc': $sortFlag = 0; break;
                    case 'desc': $sortFlag = 1; break;
                }
            }

            $dir = "files";
            $exclude = array( ".","..","error_log","_notes" );

            if (is_dir($dir)) {
                $files = scandir($dir, $sortFlag);
                foreach($files as $file){
                    if(!in_array($file,$exclude)){
                        echo '
                        <li><h3>' . $file . ' </h3></li>';
                    }
                }
            }

            ?>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `SCANDIR_SORT_NONE`, `SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING` and `SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING` constants are just integers that PHP uses in a meaningful way. You can assign these constants to variables as you desire and manipulate this variable based on your form input.

```
$sortFlag = SCANDIR_SORT_NONE; // set a default
if (!empty($_GET['valone'])) $sortFlag = SCAN_SORT_ASCENDING;
if (!empty($_GET['valtwo'])) $sortFlag = SCAN_SORT_DESCENDING;
$files = scandir($dir, $sortFlag);
// ...
```

Your form:

```
<form class="controlform" method="get" action="">
    <input type="radio" name="valone" value="Milk">Ascending
    <input type="radio" name="valtwo" value="Milk">Descending
    <button class="sortbutton">Sort!/button><br>
</form>
```

I'd probably fix the `radio` elements to use the same `name` attribute:

```
<form class="controlform" method="get" action="">
    <input type="radio" name="sort" value="asc">Ascending
    <input type="radio" name="sort" value="desc">Descending
    <button class="sortbutton">Sort!/button><br>
</form>
```

Then your PHP code can look more like this:

```
$sortFlag = SCANDIR_SORT_NONE; // set a default
if (!empty($_GET['sort'])) {
    switch ($_GET['sort']) {
        case 'asc': $sortFlag = SCAN_SORT_ASCENDING; break;
        case 'desc': $sortFlag = SCAN_SORT_DESCENDING; break;
    }
}
$files = scandir($dir, $sortFlag);
// ...
```

Comment: Well THAT'S really smart and elegant, thanks! What would you say is the best way to bring the form to the action? Should I put the PHP in an external file and connect it to the php form via GET? Sorry, new to PHP

Comment: @Marc Oh, you could leave it in the same file and just use `GET`. That's probably more appropriate actually. I'm editing my answer. That way if the user uses the forward/back/reload buttons, they won't get a "do you want to resubmit the form data" warning.

Comment: Hey @sjagr thanks for your fast reply, have a look at my updated question presenting my current solution. Can you see why there is no output at all? Doublechecked everything.

Comment: @Marc You should post a new question, but from my quick observations, it seems that `is_dir` is probably returning `false`. Does the `files` directory exist relative to your executing script?

Comment: Whoops, sorry, just found the solution, updated the following: 

        case 'asc': $sortFlag = 0; break;
        case 'desc': $sortFlag = 1; break;

0 represents "ascending" and 1 "descending" now everything works.